# How to replace character from middle of a spool file?

Tags: sql, linux, database, shell, unix

i have a table with the below attributes

```
NAME  COUNTRY CONTINENT ADD1     ADD2 ADD3 ADD4 ADD5  PINCODE
-----------------------------------------------------------
Adam   USA     NA        NYC      NY                  xxxxxx
Rakesh INDIA   ASIA      MUMBAI        MH             yyyyyy
Paul   UK      EU        LONDON   ENG                 zzzzzz
```

*from this i have created a spool file file.txt in linux which will hold the below value*

**file.txt**

```
Adam|USA|NA|NYC|NY||||xxxxxx
Rakesh|INDIA|ASIA|MUMBAI||MH|||yyyyyy
Paul|UK|EU|LONDON|ENG||||zzzzzz
```

This spool file will run on loop for every line.

For every line i want to store the required output in one variable *l_addresses*

Thus if we do **echo "$l_addresses"**, it should give the required output for every line.

**Required Output**

```
NYC NY "" "" ""
MUMBAI "" MH "" ""
LONDON ENG "" "" ""
```

Comment: `cut -d"|" -f4,5,6,7,8` is a start. To output `""` if the field if empty, I would use `awk` that can manage condition IIRC. Otherwise, ` tr "|" " "` can replace `|` by a single space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F\| '{                                           # set field separator
    for(i=4;i<=8;i++)                                   # loop wanted fields
        printf "%s%s",($i==""?"\"\"":$i),(i==8?ORS:OFS) # replace nulls and delims
}' file
```

OUtput:

```
NYC NY "" "" ""
MUMBAI "" MH "" ""
LONDON ENG "" "" ""
```